# my local FetchAPI pseudo server is throwing an error when I try to get available time for the selected date (react app)

Tags: reactjs, forms, fetch-api

Good afternoon. I'm stuck with an assignment, and since I'm just learning, I can't seem to find a solution. The task seems quite simple: When selecting a date, the available timeslots should change depending on what date I receive from FetchAPI. Based on the console output, the program correctly determines the date I select, but the error occurs at the stage of receiving timeslots from FetchAPI. I will be very glad to see your advice!

[error FetchAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLRKd.png)

**BookingPage.js**

```
import BookingForm from './BookingForm'
import React, {useReducer} from 'react'
import {fetchAPI} from './mockAPI'




export default function BookingPage() {

  const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes, initializeTimes());

  function initializeTimes() {

    fetchAPI()
        .then(times => {
            const availableTimes = [...times];
            dispatch({ type: 'update_times', availableTimes });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching available times:', error);
        });
    return [
        '17:00',
        '18:00',
        '19:00',
        '20:00',
        '21:00',
        '22:00'
    ];
}


function updateTimes(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'update_times':
          const { selectedDate } = action;
          console.log('Selected Date(2):', selectedDate);

          fetchAPI(selectedDate)
              .then(times => {
                  const availableTimes = [...times];
                  dispatch({ type: 'update_times_success', availableTimes });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  console.error('Error fetching available times:', error);
              });
          return state;
      default:
          return state;
  }
}


      const handleDateChange = (selectedDate) => {
        console.log('Selected Date(1): ', selectedDate)
        dispatch({ type: 'update_times', selectedDate });
    };

    return (
        <>
        <div id='booking'>
            <BookingForm
            availableTimes={availableTimes}
            handleDateChange={handleDateChange}
            />
        </div>
        </>
    )}
```

**mockAPI.js**

```
const availableTimesByDate = {
    '2023-11-29': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-01': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-02': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-03': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-04': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-05': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-06': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-07': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-08': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-09': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-10': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-11': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-12': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-13': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-14': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-15': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-16': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-17': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-18': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
    '2023-12-19': ['20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],
    '2023-12-20': ['17:00', '18:00', '19:00'],
  };


  const fetchAPI = (date) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            if(availableTimesByDate[date]){
                resolve(availableTimesByDate[date])
                console.log('Available Dates:', Object.keys(availableTimesByDate));
            }
            else{
                reject(new Error('No available times for the selected date.'));
            }
        } , 1000)
    })
  }

  const submitAPI = (formData) => {

    availableTimesByDate[formData.date] = availableTimesByDate[formData.date].filter(time => time !== formData.time);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (formData) {
          resolve(true); // Simulate successful submission
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Form submission failed.'));
        }
      }, 1000); // Simulate API delay
    });
  };

  export{fetchAPI,submitAPI}
```

**BookingForm.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import homeLogo from './icons_assets/home-5-512.png'



export default function BookingForm({availableTimes, handleDateChange}) {


    const [date, setDate] = useState('');
    const [guests, setGuests] = useState('');
    const [occasion, setOccasion] = useState('');
    const [time, setTime] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setOccasion('');
        setGuests('');
        setTime('')
        setDate('');
        console.log("Form submitted :", time, date, guests, occasion );
 }

    const timeSelections = availableTimes?.map((time, index) => {
            return (
                <option
                 value={time}
                 key={index}
                 >
                 {time}
                </option>
                )});

     const handleDateChangeUpdate = (e) => {
     const selectedDate = e.target.value;
     setDate(selectedDate);
     handleDateChange(selectedDate);
};

    return (
        <>
          <div className='homeIcon'>
             <a href="/">
                <img src={homeLogo} alt='Homepage Icon' />
              </a>
          </div>
 <section>
            <header>
                <div className='heading'>
                    <p>Little Lemon</p>
                    <p>Chicago</p>
                </div>
            </header>

     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <label htmlFor="res-date">Date</label>
        <input
            type="date"
            id="res-date"
            onChange={handleDateChangeUpdate}
            value={date}
        />

        <label htmlFor="res-time">Time</label>
        <select
            id="res-time"
            onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
            value={time}
            >
                {timeSelections}
        </select>

        <label htmlFor="guests">Number of guests</label>
        <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="1-10"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            id="guests"
            onChange={(e) => setGuests(e.target.value)}
            value={guests}
        />

        <label htmlFor="occasion">Occasion</label>
        <select
            id="occasion"
            onChange={(e) => setOccasion(e.target.value)}
            value={occasion}
         >
                <option value='' disabled >Select</option>
                <option value='Birthday'>Birthday</option>
                <option value='Anniversary'>Anniversary</option>
                <option value='Engagement'>Engagement</option>
        </select>
        <input disabled={!date || !time || !guests || !occasion} type="submit" value="Reserve a Table" id="button"/>
     </form>
</section>
</>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called `fetchApi` in `BookingForm` without an argument, so this call `initializeTimes` will cause the error at least once (twice for strict dev mode) - ( and every time component rerenders).

```js
  const fetchAPI = (date) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            if(availableTimesByDate[date]){
                resolve(availableTimesByDate[date])
                console.log('Available Dates:', Object.keys(availableTimesByDate));
            }
            else{
                reject(new Error('No available times for the selected date.'));
            }
        } , 1000)
    })
  }
```

maybe you should add `if else` to handle `undefined` `date` and return init data?

```js
  const fetchAPI = (date) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            if(availableTimesByDate[date]){
                resolve(availableTimesByDate[date])
                console.log('Available Dates:', Object.keys(availableTimesByDate));
            }
            else{
                resolve([]);
            }
        } , 1000)
    })
  }
```

If you dont really want to return default times, simply return empty for `undefined` date (you can also do that for not matched in `availableTimesByDate` which would be better on the Front side.

Also your `initializeTimes` returns hardcoded values, is it needed?

Maybe instead use

```
const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes, []);
```

Remove `initializeTimes` and update reducer

```
function updateTimes(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'update_times_success':
          const { availableTimes } = action;
          return availableTimes;
      case 'update_times_failure':
        return [];
      default:
          return state;
  }
}


  const handleDateChange = async (selectedDate) => {
    console.log('Selected Date(1): ', selectedDate)

    try {
      const times = await fetchAPI(selectedDate);
      dispatch({ type: 'update_times_success', availableTimes });
    } catch(error){
      console.error('Error fetching available times:', error);
      dispatch({ type: 'update_times_failure' });
    }
  };
```

This way on date change, the fetch will start, once done times are stored in reducer via success action, on error failure action will clear times.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I've checked what log out in fetchAPI (console.log([date]) and it's EXACTLY that date which I choose( and it is in correct format YYYY-MM-DD)..So it must work, but it doesn't. I tried to implement your tip with if else, but cause I'm new in programming, I can't figure out how to do it correct

Comment: The error is gone, and all console.log output correct data, but there is blank field of time form now, so nothing to select

Comment: For that you need to design what is the default initial state, blank field of time is not a problem, just make sure that user needs to select a date first (you could for instance retrieve allowed dates from API).